# How to build a Web Based UI for selenium(python) script

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I created a selenium script in python to send whatsapp message.
How can run that script with the help of a webpage

Answer (score 0):

You could create a local server in Python (using [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/) for example) that will receive requests sent from the webpage, which it will then, in turn, processes by running your Selenium script.